# How to fix django's db_type deprecation warning?

Tags: django, deprecated, dbtype

After upgrading to a more recent Django version, I started getting this deprecation warning:

```
Django version 1.3, using settings 'demos.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
/Users/.....myfile.py:328: DeprecationWarning: inner has been called without providing a connection argument. 
  if 'integer' in x.db_type()
```

I realized it's caused by the Field.db_type method, which returns the database column data type for a Field. This method has been modified so to comply with the multi-database feature of recent versions of Django, so now it also requires a connection object as argument  [[check the django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#custom-database-types)

But how to pass that connection object? I don't get it..

Answer (score 0):

... I found a solution that works. It's enough to import the connection from django.db, and pass that as an argument:

```
from django.db import connection 
if 'integer' in x.db_type(connection=connection):
    # do something...
```

Still wonder whether it's the right way of doing it though....